# Can't change the var value outside function

Tags: node.js

I need to change the value of `result` var, but I'm not getting.

My code:

```
var request = require('request');
var result = ""

function getQuote(callback){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        request({'method': 'GET','url': 'https://blockchain.info/ticker'}, function (error, response) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
           return resolve(callback(response.body))
        })
    })
}

getQuote((data) => { result = data })

console.log(result) // return is empty
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to read something about javascript execution flow. To cut long story short you ask javascript to execute asynchronous your callback and then immediately print the value of variable result _before_ execution of the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getQuote` is an asynchronous function. When you call `console.log(result)`, it may not call the callback function `(data) => { result = data }` you passed in while `getQuote` is still waiting for the response of your request. So, result is still the initialized value which is empty string.

try to log the result after the promise is fulfilled, such as `getQuote((data) => { result = data }).then(()=>console.log(result))`

Comment: I needed to change the value of the `result` variable to use its value globally. I have no idea how to do this, could you help me?

Comment: You can put all your rest code inside the `then`. If your rest code is too long or complicated, you may need some encapsulation. You can only use it after it's been set. This is the javascript asynchronous execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript engine will not wait for the promise to finish executing. Immediately after calling getQuote(), it will proceed executing the next line, i.e,  console.log(result), which is simply empty and not yet assigned any value, because it will take some time to finish completing Promise-Get method.

You need to research and understand Javascript Execution Context and Event Looping.
https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff